# Replace the end of a string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a path name thats a xml and im trying to replace it with.pdf .

I am trying to do it like this:

"files" is a string, for example its value is 123456.xml or 123456.XML

```
else if(files.endsWith(".XML") || files.endsWith(".xml")){
            String pdfName = files.replace(".xml", ".pdf");
            derp = db.getDerpyName(pdfName);
            XMLobj.Process(files, derp);
}
```

When I do a print of pdfname its still 123456.xml

Im trying to make it 123456.pdf

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to convert your file from `.xml` to `.pdf` ? or just rename ?

Comment: Its just a rename, I have a PDF in a database I'm trying to find based off an XML/xml file(the pdf has the same file name its just .pdf instead of .XML).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumptions must be wrong, I tested this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String files = "123456.xml";
    String pdfName = files.replace(".xml", ".pdf");
    System.out.println(pdfName);
}
```

The output is

```
123456.pdf
```

**EDIT:**
Based on your comment asking for case insensitivity, you could do -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String files = "123456.XML";
    int index = files.toLowerCase().indexOf(".xml");
    String pdfName;
    if (index > -1) {
        pdfName = files.substring(0, index) + ".pdf";
    } else {
        pdfName = files + ".pdf";
    }
    System.out.println(pdfName);
}
```

Which will also output

```
123456.pdf
```

Comment: O hells bells, the xml files are either XML or xml. Do you know to ignore case with the replace? I updated the question.

Comment: @user1857654 Edited to include an example that will ignore case.

Comment: You can use `String.replaceAll` as it accepts a *regex* for the search string. You can easily formulate a *regex* to replace it in a case-insensitive way.

Comment: Have a look at the Apache Commons lang library, specifically StringUtils.replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement) - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.2.1/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Use this and it will work even if the name is .XML or .xml :)

```
 files.replaceAll("(?i)\.xml", ".pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just like this for replace with ignore case with regx:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String files = "123456.XML";
    String pdfName = files.replaceAll("(?i)xml", "pdf");
    System.out.println(pdfName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String pdfName = files.replace(".xml",".pdf").replace(".XML",".pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sample code you have posted in your question, you should change it as follows:

```
else if(files.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml")){ 
                // ^ checks every possibility such as ".XML", ".xMl", ".Xml", and so on
    String pdfName = files.replaceAll("(?i)\.xml", ".pdf");
                            // ^ as per other answers, replaces case-insensitive
    derp = db.getDerpyName(pdfName);
    XMLobj.Process(files, derp);
}
```

This has the potential problem of doing unnecessary replacement in a filename like `My.xml.file.xml` which will become `My.pdf.file.pdf`.

If you need to avoid that and you only want `My.xml.file.pdf`, you can use the following regex instead: `"(?i)\.xml$"` or `"(?i)\.xml\Z"`